# How to run "assess" that's inside my makefile?

Tags: c++, c, random, makefile, nist

As you can [see in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/saamerm/NIST-Statistical-Test-Suite-CPP-Language/tree/main/sts-2.1.2), I downloaded a solution from [NIST Random Number Generator Test Suite](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/random-bit-generation/documentation-and-software) that contains a `makefile` and `C` files in the subdirectories.

According to [pg 96 of the documentation](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf) provided, I have to run `make` and then run `assess 100` (or any other number). I was able to successfully run `make` but I can't seem to run `assess 100`, as it just says "command not found". It's supposed to display this I believe:
[image: Assess command result]

I tried to go through [this makefile tutorial](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Enewhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html) but I wasn't able to understand what's going on. What do I do?

Here's the top snippet of the makefile, if it helps:

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
GCCFLAGS = -c -Wall
ROOTDIR = .
SRCDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/src
OBJDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/obj
VPATH  = src:obj:include

OBJ = $(OBJDIR)/assess.o $(OBJDIR)/frequency.o $(OBJDIR)/blockFrequency.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/cusum.o $(OBJDIR)/runs.o $(OBJDIR)/longestRunOfOnes.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/serial.o $(OBJDIR)/rank.o $(OBJDIR)/discreteFourierTransform.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/nonOverlappingTemplateMatchings.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/overlappingTemplateMatchings.o $(OBJDIR)/universal.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/approximateEntropy.o $(OBJDIR)/randomExcursions.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/randomExcursionsVariant.o $(OBJDIR)/linearComplexity.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/dfft.o $(OBJDIR)/cephes.o $(OBJDIR)/matrix.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/utilities.o $(OBJDIR)/generators.o $(OBJDIR)/genutils.o

assess: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) -lm

$(OBJDIR)/assess.o: $(SRCDIR)/assess.c defs.h decls.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $(SRCDIR)/assess.c
...
```

Comment: Try `./assess 100` instead of just `assess 100`.  Does that work?

Comment: Ah dang, yes that worked. How did you figure it out? And what am I dealing with here? I have done C a long time ago, and never used makefile before

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with the makefile.  Your computer is set up so you have to type that leading `./` to run an executable in the current directory; this is a safety feature.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548083/what-is-the-use-of-adding-dot-in-path-variable

Comment: It's not so much "figuring it out" as it is having basic experience in using a shell.  Now you know, so you have acquired a new understanding.

Comment: I just noticed you guys are top 0.1% and 0.4% of all of StackOverflow. It's an honour to have my question by you guys! Thanks :) @zwol You want to put an answer so I can mark it as correct?